# rptdesign file cannot be preview in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, birt

I'm using APIs provided by Eclipse BIRT for generating BIRT reports in my application since a few days and I haven't any problem to preview the generated reports from eclipse up to now. 
Since this morning it doesn't work. it doesn't show any exception. it shows a blank report without any element inside him.

Do anyone find any explanation for this?

NOTE1: I use BIRT in windows 7 OS. I hear that there are problems to preview report from eclipse on Windows 8 OS. But it isn't my case.

NOTE2: I haven't done any update in my computer recently.

Answer (score 2):

> birtprofi @ http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/30484-birt-report-not-running-in-eclipse-after-update-to-windows-81/page-2

Solution for workaround to use internal browser with IE 11:

1. Open eclipse.ini File (same path as eclipse.exe)
2. Insert those 2 lines at the end of the script:

   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=ie,mozilla

   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=7000

Restart Eclipse BIRT Designer. Then it should be possible to use the internal web browser with IE 11

Answer (score 1):

You should set defaul browser app. If you dont have any default browser app birt will not open anything.

**For Windows 10**

**Settings - > System - > Default Apps - Web Browser**
Set default browser.

Also for **windows 8** is the smilar.